# Integrating Elastic search in Magento EE 2.1.2

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, elasticsearch

I want to integrate Elastic search in Magento EE 2.1.2. I have installed elastic search instance and did configuration in Magento Admin. When I click on TEST CONNECTION button in Admin it says **`Successful! Test Again?`**

[image]

I want to know how Elasticsearch processes the search request. I want to check the search query on elascticsearch server.

When I hit my elastic search from browser I get this result:

```
name    "My First Node"
cluster_name    "mycluster1"
version 
number  "2.3.1"
build_hash  "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39"
build_timestamp "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "5.5.0"
tagline "You Know, for Search"
```

Comment: Hence you are using `Magento EE 2.1.2` and it's licensed version so I think on one can give you the exact code, But sometimes ago I was on the same situation and I can say that you can get your starting point `module-elasticsearch`

Answer (score 1):

You can get details about your Elasticsearch indices through a GET request (curl for example, or straight from your browser). Assuming your port is set to the default `9200`, you can do this to get your indices:

http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v

Here you will see a list of indices that Magento 2 is using, in our case it is named "magento2_product_1_v2".

You can they do a search query on this index to test if your data is present (the `pretty` param just means the output should be displayed in a readable format instead of raw JSON):

http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_2_v2/_search?pretty=true&q=[QUERY]

To view your entire index you can use:

http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_2_v2/_search?pretty=true&q=*

More info here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/_exploring_your_cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check your elastic search reindex status here.

http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/head/

You can select structured query/ Any request tab and search your queries.